# HTML5 form placeholder fallback with form validation in Prototype

Tags: forms, validation, html, placeholder, fallback

I've got an HTML5 form on my page with an email input that has place holder text in it. It works beautifully and I love the native validation!

I'm not sure how to serve old browsers best. I'm using a bit of javascript that copies the placeholder's text and imprints it as a value. It works well, but then the form validation goes off because there's text that isn't an email address in the form.

I do not want to lose the validation.. Any ideas?

HTML

```
<input id="email" type="email" placeholder="Enter your email address">
```

JavaScript (Prototype):

```
var Placeholder = Class.create({
    initialize: function (element) {
        this.element = element;
        this.placeholder = element.readAttribute('placeholder');
        this.blur();
        Event.observe(this.element, 'focus', this.focus.bindAsEventListener(this));
        Event.observe(this.element, 'blur', this.blur.bindAsEventListener(this));
    },
    focus: function () {
        if (this.element.hasClassName('placeholder'))
            this.element.clear().removeClassName('placeholder');
    },
    blur: function () {
        if (this.element.value === '')
            this.element.addClassName('placeholder').value = this.placeholder;
    }
});
Event.observe(window, 'load', function(e){
    new Placeholder($('email'));

});
```

EDIT:

Wouldn't it be great if browsers supporting placeholder ignored the value attribute?

EDIT 2:

No, I don't want to set the input type to text. That will change the validation's behavior from email syntax to spellcheck.

Comment: Is this custom validation you're writing or are you using a validation plugin?

Comment: Neither, it's the browser's native validation. Read here: http://diveintohtml5.org/forms.html

Comment: I'm familiar with that - I was assuming you were providing your own validation for older browsers, but I think I'm misunderstanding the problem as you describe it. You use javascript to put the placeholder text in the input field, but in html5 supporting browsers, this causes validation to trigger because it's not actually an email address?

Comment: Exactly! If push comes to shove I'll change my value/placeholder text to "enteryouremailaddress@example.com"

Comment: Well, it seems to me that you don't want the user to leave that placeholder text there, so having it caught by validation seems like a good thing.

Comment: It's visually disturbing. I have the css set for a red border if it's invalid. Don't want it to load that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

User [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) to detect support for placeholder and only use your javascript to copy the placeholder text if support doesn't exist:

```
if(!Modernizr.input.placeholder){
  // copy placeholder text to input
}
```

This will prevent it from doing the copy on browsers supporting html5 form attributes like placeholder.

Comment: All current browser, which do support HTML5 validation, also do support the placeholder attribute (Opera 11+, Chrome 10+, FF4.0+, IE10 do support both; only Opera lower than 11 does only support validation) . This means kinakutas code should help. If you don't want to use Modernizr to test, you can the following code:

`if( !'placeholder' in document.createElement('input') ){}`

Comment: Originally didn't want to use Modernizr because of it's weight and an http request, but decided to use a configured build for just the input feature detection and ran that in my plugins script file at the bottom of the document. Didn't have to worry about a FOUC (http://paulirish.com/2009/avoiding-the-fouc-v3/) because it's placeholder text, not an actual element. Hallelujah!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<input  type="email"   value="Enter Email" 
onfocus="if (this.value == 'Enter Email')  {this.value = '';}"
onblur="if (this.value =='') {this.value = 'Enter Email';}" />
```

Comment: if the input type is set to text the validation is spell checking. I want to maintain the email syntax validation, so the type has to remain "email"

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but it could help other users that come across this question.

You can use this http://afarkas.github.com/webshim/demos/demos/webforms.html for form validation with support for older browsers. It sits on top of jQuery and Modernizer and is pretty easy to implement.

Hope it helps.